# Force users to enable notifications in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api, notifications

I have a messenger on my website, which creates desktop notifications for users via WEB API.

First time the webpage asks users to enable the notifications, however most of them automatically click on `disable`, even without reading what is asked. Therefore, they woudn't receive the notifications ever.

Is there a way to force them to enable the notifications? 
Going to browser's settings to enable would be difficult for some users...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you cannot force them. You could perhaps display some information stating that they must enable notification in order for your messenger to work properly.

Not asking for permission would be a dream for malicous websites.

the w3c specification states the following regarding this:

> 4.3 Permission
>
> Notifications can only be displayed if the user (or user agent on behalf of the user) has granted permission. The permission to display notifications for a given origin can be one of three strings:
>   "default"
>   This is equivalent to "denied", but the user has made no explicit choice thus far.
>
> "denied"
>   This means the user does not want notifications.
>
> "granted"
>   This means notifications can be displayed.
>
> There is no equivalent to "default" meaning "granted". In that case "granted" is >simply returned as there would be no reason for the application to ask for >permission.

Comment: May I write a script, so users just click on the button and enable notifications? :)

Comment: Or if denied, to set as default? That would have sense